# How to create service account for firebase to use with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Am building a server with `firebase cloud functions` and I need other servers to call my server endpoints. The most important thing is that I need these third party domains calling my server to be authenticated.

**Question 1:** How can I create such a service account, include the service account credentials in the call and extract `idToken`from it.

**Question 2:** Is there a tool I can use to test this during development once I know how to make such secure calls, for example, how to do this using **Postman REST application** or any other preferred tool.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some thoughts for #1, at least.  Check out the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens.

Whoever is calling your service needs to be logged in to Firebase so that it can send an ID token (see the section titled "Retrieve ID tokens on clients"), and your service will need to then verify the token (see the section titled "Verify ID tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK").

I have never tried to emulate the client side of this type of interaction through Postman or anything similar, unfortunately I cannot help with that part of your question.